# sed-compatible regex matching the middle word of an odd number of words

Tags: regex, sed

How can one use a regex to capture the middle word of an odd number of whitespace-separated words, assuming the number of words is always odd? Any `sed`-compatible regex would do, including extended (`sed -r`).

For example:  (input  capture)

- "apple"  "apple"
- "zero one two"  "one"
- "red blue green orange yellow"  "green"

I suspect that this might be impossible without some of the extensions provided by more powerful regex libraries, such as PCRE, and I believe it is impossible under the classical formal-language definition of a regular expression.
In case this is impossible to do with `sed`, how might one use the features of a different regex engine to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Oops, you forgot to post your code! StackOverflow is about helping people fix their code. It's not a free coding service. Any code is better than no code at all. Meta-code, even, will demonstrate how you're thinking a program should work, even if you don't know how to write it.

Answer (score 3):

### Using sed

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/^[^ ]+ //; s/ [^ ]+$//; ta;' file
apple
one
green
```

The above assumes GNU sed.  For BSD (OSX) sed, some minor modifications would be required.

#### How it works

- `:a`

  This defines label `a`.
- `s/^[^ ]+ //; s/ [^ ]+$//`

  The first of these substitution commands removes a word and a space from the beginning of the line.  The second removes a space and word from the end.

  This has the effect of removing words both ends of the line until there is only one word left.
- `ta`

  If the above substitution commands did result in a substitution, then branch to label `a`.

  When the line has only one word left, then the substitutions do nothing and the branching stops.

### Using awk

With awk, we can access the middle word directly:

```
$ awk '{print $((NF+1)/2)}' file
apple
one
green
```

In awk, `NF` is the number of fields.  If there are an odd number of fields, as per this question, then `(NF+1)/2` is the number of the middle field.

Comment: It may be worth pointing out that if there are an *even* number of fields (in case of bad input), then `(NF+1)/2` will refer to the first of the two middle fields (so awk rounds down).